# Sorting function doesn't pass the parameter to the comparing function

Tags: c++, sorting, compare

The purpose of the code is to arrange the given array of integers such that they form the largest number. The output should be a string due to the overflow problem.
The code works perfectly for input-

n = 5

nums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

But the same code doesn't work for the input -

n = 27

nums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

After hours of trying, I found that that the error is in the sorting line. Can you help me figure out the reason for the error?
***sort(strs.begin(), strs.end(), compareStr);***

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool compareStr(string st1, string st2){
    //cout << "st1 -- " << st1 << endl;
    //cout << "st2 -- " << st2 << endl;
    if (st1.size() == st2.size()){
        return (st1 <= st2);
    }
    else if (st1.size() < st2.size()){
        int len = st1.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len ; i++){
            if (st1[i] < st2[i]){
                return true;
            }
            else if (st1[i] > st2[i]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return compareStr(st1,st2.substr(len));
    }
    else {
        int len = st2.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len ; i++){
            if (st1[i] < st2[i]){
                return true;
            }
            else if (st1[i] > st2[i]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return compareStr(st1.substr(len),st2);
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> nums;
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
        int k;
        cin >> k;
        nums.push_back(k);
    }
    vector<string> strs; 
    //cout << to_string(11)+"12" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
        strs.push_back(to_string(nums[i]));
    }
    cout << strs.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++){
        cout << i << " - " << strs[i] << endl;
    }
    sort(strs.begin(), strs.end(), compareStr);
    string ans = "";
    for (int i = strs.size()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
            //cout << strs[i] << endl;
            ans = ans+strs[i]; 
            //cout << ans << endl;
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

When I print the st1 value inside the comparing function it shows that it is empty.

Comment: `return (st1 <= st2);` needs to be `return (st1 < st2);` The predicate of `std::sort()` must sort values based on [Strict Weak Ordering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), but `<=` breaks that. See the [Compare requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) for details

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you so much.